# Named Entities in NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to get the named entities in a small test using stanford NER tagger. Here is the code:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser')
print st.tag('Ram offers computer science course'.split())
```

Output I get is:

```
[(u'Ram', u'O'), (u'offers', u'O'), (u'computer', u'O'), (u'science', u'O'), (u'course', u'O')]
```

I am not getting why all the tags are 'O'. While Ram is a person, Computer is an object,science and course are also classifiable objects.

Is there any way I can get named entities for my sentence Like below:

```
Ram -> Person
Coputer Science -> Course
```

Comment: I tried to run the example on http://corenlp.run/. However, seems like StandfordNER cannot tag Named Entity Recognition in this particular example. One option is to see OpenIE relationship, it gives `[{'object': 'computer science course',  'objectSpan': [2, 5],  'relation': 'offers',   'relationSpan': [1, 2],  'subject': 'Ram',  'subjectSpan': [0, 1]}]`

Comment: is there any way I can get course names? Say, My sentence is "SDGI is offering courses like Electronics,Mechatronics, Physics,Mechanical Engineering"

Comment: The default models for Stanford NER will not identify course names. You will need to train your own models OR if you can define rules or find a list, use it as a gazzeteer.